# Mongoose query with find and as a result the field name where i found results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to have as a result of my query the field i found the regex,  example :

If i find the result in facebook field;

Lets say my req.body.key = 'crazy' and inside my db i have 'crazy' in facebook field. I want as a result of the query my CitizenProfile model more the field or fields i found the result. In this case the field name 'facebook'

Obs: This query is already giving the model i just need the field or fields name where it found match with regex.
Can this be achieve? Thanks!

```
    app.post('/v1/profile/search', (req, res) => {
    async.waterfall([
        function (next) {
            CitizenProfile.find({
                $or: [{'first_name': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}}, {'middle_name': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}},
                    {'last_name': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}}, {'email': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}},
                    {'facebook': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}}, {'linkedin': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}},
                    {'skills': {$regex: req.body.key, $options:'i'}}],
                'id_citizen': {$ne: req.body.id_citizen},
                'is_hidden': {$ne: true}
            })
                .exec(function (err, data) {
                   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MongoDB has that kind of feature (correct me anyone if I am wrong).

Since you are only getting back the documents matching the regular expression, you'll have to apply the regular expression on those same documents again to find the fields.

Untested but I think you would do something like

```
let regex = new RegExp(req.body.key, 'i');

CitizenProfile.find({
    $or: [
        { 'first_name': regex }, 
        { 'middle_name': regex },
        { 'last_name': regex }, 
        { 'email': regex },
        { 'facebook': regex }, 
        { 'linkedin': regex },
        { 'skills': regex }
    ],
    'id_citizen': { $ne: req.body.id_citizen },
    'is_hidden': { $ne: true }
}).exec(function (err, profiles) => {   
    // loop through found documents
    profiles.forEach(function (profile) {
        profile = profile.toJSON();
        // filter fields based on regular expression
        let keys = Object.keys(profile).filter(k => regex.test(profile[k]));
        // do something with keys
        console.log(keys);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks is what i was looking for ; D